# Remove Spacing in a Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I would like to align text to left the same like edittext as shown in the picture. But, deafult spinner include that spacing. So, I would like to remove it to align text to left. Does anyone know how to fix it?

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSakt.png)

Comment: You want to remove the red marked space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a layout name `spinner_text.xml`. Paste this code in it:

```
<TextView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAlignment="textStart"
android:gravity="start"
android:maxLines="1"
/>
```

Then Edit your java code. Change Java adapter like this.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.spinner_text,paths);
```

(Change your layout like above).

Then Spinner text will be aligned with the text. 
Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just add some extra minus margin in your xml spinner layout. Don't need to create custom textview layout.

Like this:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerDistrict"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="-6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/basic_margin_padding_min"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/basic_margin_padding_min"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

That's it!